# Reference request: prestacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-stacks

Prestacks do not arise often in nature so people do not write about their properties, sadly I found one in the wild.

I've tried finding a reference which proves basic properties of prestacks, but all I can find are properties of stacks and a definition of prestacks. Ideally I would like a natural reference to cite. I've tried to find mention in the stacks project and failed [perhaps I am incompetent?] as this would be the best thing to cite.

The results I am interested in are:

1. Does the category of prestacks admit colimits? (I could probably prove this, but it is more natural to cite).
2. If I construct a morphism from a prestack F to a stack F' and show it is an isomorphism on stalks then does the stackification of F coincide with F'. (I expect something along the lines of "stacks are local" to be true. I could probably prove the right statement with enough time but once again it would be more natural to cite).

Comment: I think it is the case that every prestack can be embedded in a stack, in the same way that every separated presheaf can be embedded in a sheaf. That may be enough for practical purposes. (One could make similar complaints about the paucity of reference material for separated presheaves… but in fact they are studied, under the more general framework of quasitoposes.)

Comment: The category of prestacks is a category of presheaves with values in a cocomplete category so it is cocomplete (and complete). It should be noted though that the right notion of (co)limit here is that of a 2-(co)limit

Comment: @leibnewtz There is another use of the word "prestack" to mean a presheaf that satisfies descent but not necessarily effective descent.

Comment: Potentially useful for 2: it's true that if $C$ is a site and $f : F\to F'$ is a morphism of stacks over $C,$ then $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if (i) For every $X\in C$, $F(X)\to F'(X)$ is fully faithful, and (ii) For every $X\in C$ and $x\in F'(X),$ there exists a covering $\{X_i\to X\}$ such that the restriction $x_i\in F'(X_i)$ of $x$ is in the essential image of $F(X_i).$ (This is exercise 4.I in Olsson's "Algebraic Spaces and Stacks").

Comment: I am interested in Leibnewtz's definition.

Thanks I'll take a look at Olsson.

I'll post a reference here if I ever find one, and if not I can always link my paper which will give a proof of these facts if no reference is to be found...